# Separating a string by the first occurrence of a separator

Tags: python, string, operation

I just got into python very recently and now I'm practicing by (what I imagine to be rather simple, but challenging enough for me) creating small tools to sort files into folders.

So far it has been going pretty well, but now I've encountered a problem:

My files are in the following format:
myAsset_prefix1_prefix2_prettyName.ext ;
(i.e. Tiger_texture_spec_brightOrange.png)

myAsset always has a different length since it's dependent on name.

I want to sort every file of the same asset ( "myAsset_" tag) in a separate folder.

The copying to a separate folder etc is no challenge but..
I don't want to update an array by hand every time I create/receive a new asset.
So instead of using the `startswith` operation and make it run through a list, I'd like to build that array when my script runs, by making the script look at the name of the file and store everything up to and including the first "_" in a variable/array.

Is that possible?

Comment: Could you please clarify how the title is related to the question?

Comment: It all starts with "asset_tag = filename.split('_')[0]"

Comment: fixed that - it was saved up from another q i ddnt post :S Sorry bout that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module. This allows you to list the files that match a certain format.

For example:

```
for filename in glob.glob(*.ext):
    asset_tag = filename.split(" ")[0]
```

Comment: Actually, what I was looking for was that .split operation :D
That actually does what I need. Thx! :D

Comment: For what it's worth, `str.partition()` is like `str.split()` but it only splits on the first occurrence of your chosen delimiter.